# Can't decode WINDOWS-1252 byte array

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

I got the following code snippet. The byte array is an excerpt of a longer one. Nevertheless, the problem becomes clear. A friend told me it's `bytea` but I struggle to decode it to a human readable string.

```
b = b'\xc1\x01\x00'

import cchardet
enc = cchardet.detect(b)['encoding'] # 'WINDOWS-1252' 

b.decode(enc) # 'Á\x01\x00'
b.decode("utf-8", errors='ignore') # '\x01\x00'
```

Any idea?

**Remark:** the data is originally created by NetVault and stored in PostgresDB in the database ‘netvault_scheduling’ with a table ‘backupslecrionset’ in the column ‘backupseltree’. The database says that the encoding is UTF-8. But my data (read into a pandas dataframe) looks like the above.

Statement looks like this:

```
   db = postgresql.open('pq://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format({user} {password},  'localhost', 51486, 
'netvault_scheduling'))

prep_stmt = db.prepare("SELECT ph.jobid, jd.title," 
"to_char(to_timestamp(ph.date),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS datum,"
"ph.duration, ph.bytestransferred, jd.clientname, bss.backupseltree"
"FROM phasehistory ph " 
"INNER JOIN jobdescription jd " 
"ON jd.jobid=ph.jobid "
"INNER JOIN backupselectionset bss "
"on jd.selectionsset = bss.name "
"WHERE jd.jobid = $1 "
"ORDER BY datum DESC ")

backup_nv_tree = prep_stmt(7228)

Df = pd.DataFrame(backup_nv_tree)
Df = ['JobID', 'Title',
                        'Date', 
                        'Duration', 'Transfered in GB',
                        'Clientname', 'Backuptree']
```

Comment: guessing encodings is a tricky business, and not foolproof. Can you paste the original byte string in its real home? Also, are you sure the byte string itself was not constructed improperly up the stream somewhere? You need to ideally be told what the encoding of the byte string really is.

Comment: I know all this ;) anyway, can't post the full string since it may contain company information. sorry.

Comment: Understandable. Makes it really tough to figure out the issue though.

Comment: Added more information to my original post.

Comment: Please show how you are retrieving the data from the Postgres database.

Comment: Added the SQL statement in Python